# Some of our Professors are Missing

Tags: knowledge, steganography, anagram

It has emerged that four members of the mathematics department at **Farthingbottom School** have been working on a top-secret code-breaker for the government.

Unfortunately for them (and the school) someone has found out and they have all gone missing. The only hope of finding them is to decode their files which are encrypted on the server.

There are six canvases hanging on the wall of their research laboratory.
The first four of these show the members of the team:

- Professor Sutherwell is pictured standing in the school grounds near
  the large letters that read "FARTHINGBOTTOM SCHOOL".
- The photo of Professor Peters shows her in the library, engrossed in
  a particularly weighty tome.
- Professor Bannister is seen at the blackboard, working on a
  particularly complex calculation.
- Professor Maxwell looks relaxed in a graveyard next to a gravestone
  that has been doctored to bear the name "Canute VI".

The Fifth canvas has been deliberately hung at a slant, but the picture on it is this:

[image]

The final canvas shows the following lines of text:

> *Madden dashed ketchup between my turkey fillets.*
>
> *Putrid steak kills the unusual smell of aromatic flowers on each jasmine plant which can be found growing around John's expansive garden in the countryside of southern Madrid.*
>
> *Burning every day, the bright fire in the temple was wasteful.*
>
> *Stow our daughter's birth certificate near the rest of our extra-precious documents, wherever they might be.*
>
> **Tony Steller**

**Question:** Can you locate the means of decrypting the files?

Comment: Image points to a place in Israel: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PikiWiki_Israel_34460_Leonardo_City_Tower_and_Diamond_Bridge.JPG

Comment: That's the Leonardo tower. Leonardo de Vinci came from Vinci, which is in Italy, close to the leaning tower of Pisa (near-ish to Vinci), and if hung deliberately at a slant, this would also be a leaning tower.

Comment: The question is tagged anagram, so I tried looking up anagrams of "Tony Steller." Several interesting results, most notably "letters only."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As noted by [Rand](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41869) and others the fifth canvas hints at:

> the Fibonacci Sequence

This is further cemented by the more subtle hints of the 2nd, 3rd & 4th canvases, which allude to:

> Leonardo of Pisa's *[Liber Abaci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liber_Abaci)* which was a "particularly weighty tome" (canvas 2) containing "complex calculations" (canvas 3) and was written in 1202, the same year that Canute VI died (canvas 4).

So extending from what Rand already tried, but with:

> the Fibonacci sequence indexing letters into each *sentence* of the sixth canvas *and* ensuring we use the *full* sequence, starting ***1***, *1*, *2*, *3*, *5*, *8*, *...*, we get (with each initial letter repeated):
>
>  ***M*ad**d**e**n d**a**shed **k**etchup b**e**tween my turke**y** fillets.
>  ***P*ut**r**i**d s**t**eak k**i**lls the u**n**usual smell of **a**romatic flowers on each **j**asmine plant which can be found growing **a**round John's expansive garden in the countryside of southern Mad**r**id.
>  ***B*ur**n**i**ng **e**very **d**ay, the br**i**ght fire in the **t**emple was wasteful.
>  ***S*to**w **o**ur **d**augh**t**er's birt**h** certificate n**e**ar the rest of our extra-p**r**ecious documents, wherever they might b**e**.

Producing:

> ***M* made a key, *P* put it in a jar, *B* buried it, *S* stood there**

So it appears that our professors worked together, with:

> Professor **M**axwell making the key, Professor **P**eters putting it in a jar, Professor **B**annister burying it, leaving Professor **S**utherwell *standing* where it is buried... Which, as can be seen in the first photo, means that the key is buried in a jar in the school grounds, near the "FARTHINGBOTTOM SCHOOL" sign.

Comment: @GordonK - Oh! :) Give me a minute to edit...

Comment: @GordonK - better? (though I still don't know what the relevance of Canute VI is...)

Comment: ROT13: Gur bgure guerr pnainfrf gbtrgure cebivqr nabgure pyhr gb Svobanppv

Comment: @GordonK - how about now?

Comment: Dammit!!! So close! +1, good job :-)

Answer (score 10):

As others have already deduced, the photograph on the fifth canvas is

> the [Leonardo Tower in Israel](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PikiWiki_Israel_34460_Leonardo_City_Tower_and_Diamond_Bridge.JPG):
>
>  [image: Leonardo Tower]

The fact that this canvas has been hung at a slant tells us that

> we're looking for a leaning tower, of which of course the most famous is [at Pisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa).

So we have the words

> **Leonardo** and **Pisa**, which when put together give us the mathematician [Leonardo of Pisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci), better known as **Fibonacci**.

Clearly this means that

> the Fibonacci numbers

are somehow involved in the solution. The obvious place to look is in the message on the sixth canvas, so we pick out

> the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 5th, 8th, 13th, 21st, 34th, 55th, 89th, 144th, and 233rd letters

to get

> **Mad**d**e**n d**a**shed **k**etchup b**e**tween my turke**y** fillets.
>
>  Putrid steak ki**l**ls the unusual smell of aromatic flower**s** on each jasmine plant which can be found growing around John's exp**a**nsive garden in the countryside of southern Madrid.
>
>  Burning every day, the bright fire in the temple was was**t**eful.
>
>  Stow our daughter's birth certificate near the rest of our extra-precious documents, wherever they might be.

**Thus the final message appears to be**

> MADE A KEY LSAT.

Maybe LSAT (L-sat?) is some electronic decryption method, or maybe this is only a partial solution. I haven't done anything with the first four canvases, of course, but there doesn't seem to be much information to be had there: just the four professors and the name "Canute VI", which may be a red herring. (Applying the same method to "Canute VI" as we did to the text of the sixth canvas gives

> **CAN**u**t**e V**I** or CAN'T I,

which doesn't seem to be any use.) Additionally, the name "Tony Steller" is, as already noted in the comments,

> an anagram of "Letters only",

but my interpretation of this is simply that we're meant to

> ignore all spaces and punctuation in the text of the sixth canvas, as I did when counting letters.

Comment: The text in the question has an *expansive* garden, not an *expensive* one, which changes one character in your extracted message.

Comment: @Gareth Oops! I replaced the target letters by asterisks when working this out in a text document, and then made a mistake when adding them back in for a clearer form here. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: I was wondering how it could have happened (surely, I thought, he can't actually have retyped it by hand)...